# Is there a more succinct for this date checking?

Tags: python, django

Every invoice may have several items and the invoice due date is the date of the earliest due item. Here's what I have but I wonder if there may be a shorter version:

```
due_date = None

for item in i.item_set.all():
    if due_date is None:
        due_date = item.due_date
    else:
        if due_date > item.due_date:
            due_date = item.due_date
```

Comment: Are you trying to get your answer directly from the database or by looping through a queryset (getting your answer in Python)?

Comment: @BrianNeal I think from Python is faster and better.

Comment: It depends. If you just want to know that one thing, making the database do the work can be orders of magnitude faster. In order for you to do get the answer in Python, Django's ORM has to bring all the data into memory and construct objects, costing time and memory.

Comment: As an example of making the database do the work, see the answer by mipadi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Django, you can do it like this:

```
invoice_date = i.item_set.order_by('due_date')[0].due_date
```

Comment: you might want to surround that by a try/catch and set the value to None if there are no items.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `min`?

```
due_date = min((item.due_date for item in i.item_set.all()))
```

Or, another option:

```
from operator import attrgetter
due_date = min(i.item_set.all(), key=attrgetter("due_date")).due_date
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that the later is somewhat different in that you'll get an item object instead of just the due_date...